# How to do a git push from within a Bamboo Script task

Tags: git, bamboo

We are treating git as a database for some of our configurations and csv files. I have a Bamboo plan where I checkout some code (from Stash), run a node script and generate some csv files.
I need to be able to 'git push' these to a certain repository. 
I have a Script task where I am writing something like this -

```
git remote add central ssh://git@stashRepoUrl:port/xyz.git 
git config --global user.name "Bamboo"
git config --global user.email "bamboo@xyz.com"

git add src/main/resources/lookups/main/common/*
git add src/main/resources/lookups/main/reference/*
git commit -m "FROM BAMBOO JOB"

git push -u central featureBranchName
```

I am getting the following error - hostkey verification failed.

How do I setup ssh between my stash repo and this 'bamboo agent'? I am sure someone might have tried this already.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manually do (just once), withthe account used by your script:

```
ssh -T git@stashRepoUrl -p port
```

That will trigger a question to which you answer yes (to update the `~/.ssh/known_hosts`)

Then your script can proceed.

Note that I would also set manually the line:

```
git remote add central ssh://git@stashRepoUrl:port/xyz.git
```

You only need to use that command once, not each time your script runs.

Comment: for both parts, we could eliminate the manual step - 1) update known_hosts but clean up afterwards 2) do a git remote remove central once work is done

Comment: @KumarVaibhav The `known_hosts` should be updated only once. No need to automate that step. The `git remote remove` is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks a bunch.. so many theories were conspiring in my head and itwas that dead simple.

Answer (score 2):

There is document in atlassian confluence How to commit to a Git repo during a build

Refer to this link
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamkb/how-to-commit-to-a-git-repo-during-a-build-720641378.html

Answer (score 1):

As an update to VonC answer you can put it in a script if you use:

```
ssh -T git@stashRepoUrl -p port -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

This will automatically accept the certificate for the machine in question if you are using docker or cleaning the agent completely.